# How do I show a ToolStripMenu after user right-clicks a ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When the user right clicks on a ToolStripMenuItem (which is part of another ToolStripMenu), I want to show a new ToolStripMenu.

I'm using Visual Basic

I tried creating a ToolStripMenu and adding an Items in code. But when right clicking (on the ToolStripMenuItem) I cannot see the new ToolStripMenu. Is it maybe because I didn't define the location where the new ToolStripMenu should be visible?

**THE CODE:**

```
Private Sub RappelVerkoopfacturenToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim tsFavorites As New ToolStrip
        tsFavorites.Items.Add("Add to favorites")
        tsFavorites.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ToolStripMenuItem can contain sub-items, I don't understand why you need to do it in code.

Comment: You can just make it in the designer and check the generated code in the .Designs.vb file

Comment: @OrMiz it's not part of that ToolStripMenu and shouldn't be visible as a subitem. This is to avoid confusion for the users

Comment: Also I need this same functionality to appear on multiple ToolStripMenuItems, not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the new `ToolStrip` to the Forms´ controls:

```
Me.Controls.Add(tsFavorites)
```

Additionally you don´t have to call the `Show()` method. Change visibility with the `Visible` property:

```
tsFavorites.Visible = True
```

(Nevertheless, the control is visible after adding it to the controls of the form by default. So you don´t have to set it explicitly.)